# Adding individual elements of two List<decimal[]> types

Tags: c#, list

I created an extension method for type `List<decimal[]>` that does element-wise addition.  The method is as follows:

```
public static void ElementAddition(this List<decimal[]> thisList, List<decimal[]> listToAdd)
{
   if (thisList.Count == 0) return;
   for (var i = 0; i < thisList.Count; i++)
   {
      for (var j = 0; j < thisList[0].Length; j++)
      {
         thisList[i][j] += listToAdd[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

This has some interesting results.  Every time the `thisList[i][j] += listToAdd[i][j];` line executes it adds ALL the elements in the one list to the other list.  So I eventually end up with `thisList` being substantially larger than it should be.  It does not do element-wise addition as I was expecting.

I struggled to find similar questions on stackoverflow so any pointers would be useful.  I clearly do not understand something about the implementation of Lists?

Paul

edit:
The following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void ElementAddition_WhenCalled_CorrectlyAddIndividualElements()
{
    var decListOne = new decimal[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    var decListTwo = new decimal[] {10, 20, 30, 40};
    var listListOne = new List<decimal[]>();
    var listListTwo = new List<decimal[]>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        listListOne.Add(decListOne);
        listListTwo.Add(decListTwo);
    }

    listListOne.ElementAddition(listListTwo);

    Assert.AreEqual(11m,listListOne[0][0]);
}
```

provides this output:

`Expected: 11m
  But was:  31m`

Comment: Why ``j < thisList[0].Length`` ?

Comment: @RandRandom: I agree, it should be `thisList[i]`.

Other than that, I don't see how this would result in the behaviour that @Paul is describing. Perhaps he's mistaken or the issue lay elsewhere.

Comment: @RandRandom,  @Chris  `j < thisList[0].Length` since all decimal[] are of the same size.  Technically `thisList[i].Length` is more correct though and I will change to same.  Yet, this is the behavior I get!

Comment: @Paul: I wrote a test here. It behaves as I expect, adding each corresponding element together: http://rextester.com/JYHG69071 EDIT: Can you edit this linked code with an example set that demonstrates what you have? Please try to produce for us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See edit to post.

Comment: @Paul: Why the `0..3` for loop?

Comment: 3 because it is just a test.  Hard coded the constraints.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` ended up with a list of 3 elements, so the result of 31 is correct.

Comment: The issue is you're reusing the same `decListOne` in the lists. So you keep adding to the same collection 3 times. Don't re-use the same collection. EDIT: Here's a version where you use 3 _different_ arrays, works as you expect: http://rextester.com/EOHAI63875 , here's a version where you use the _same referenced array_ 3 times, producing the result you see now: http://rextester.com/OOFXG15884

Comment: @MartinE I feel somewhat like an idiot right now.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair MartinE is absolutely correct.  The outcome is 100% what it should be.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time but thanks for the awesome response.

Comment: @Paul: No, the loop is fine. I see what you're doing. You're trying to build a collection with 3 arrays in it. That's fine. The issue is that you're reusing _the same referenced array_ 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the same array 3 times in your test:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    listListOne.Add(decListOne); //here's the problem
    listListTwo.Add(decListTwo);
}
```

This means in your `ElementAddition`, you adding the elements back into the same collection on each loop. The assumption that each entry of `thisList` is referencing a different array is incorrect.

If you change your test to ensure each array is unique/different:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    listListOne.Add(decListOne.ToArray()); //force new/different instances of the array
    listListTwo.Add(decListTwo);
}
```

Then you will get the result you expect.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change following:

```
for (var j = 0; j < thisList[0].Length; j++)
{
}
```

to:

```
for (var j = 0; j < thisList[i].Length; j++)
{
}
```

Comment: I have done this since it is more correct even though it was not technically required but it has not changed the outcome.